# Changing the values in multiple parts of a grid (list of strings?)

Tags: python

I'm making a 10-by-10 grid of `0`s. I want to be able to change (for example) the top 5 rows to "ONE" through an if statement.

What's the best way to go about doing it without targeting each individual `0`?

I've tried doing something like `grid[:5][:5]` to target multiple `0`s, but that doesn't do anything.

```
grid = [[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]

number = 1

if number is 1:
    grid[:5][:5] = "ONE"

for row in grid:
    print(" ".join(map(str, row)))
```

Comment: `numpy` allows this sort of indexing: `arr[:5, :5] = 1` with basic lists slicing is like copying a section so taking a slice of a slice is just a partial copy of a partial copy, not 2D indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two nested `for` loops:

```
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(10):
        grid[row][col] = 'ONE'
```

Answer (score 0):

As grid[:5][:5] returns a new list, changing the new list would not yield the results you want.

```
grid = [[0]*10 for x in range(10)] #pythonic way of making a list/list of list (grid)

number = 1
if number == 1:
    for x in xrange(5):
        for y in xrange(10):
            grid[x][y] = "ONE"

print(grid)
```

Output:

```
[['ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE'],
 ['ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE'],
 ['ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE'],
 ['ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE'],
 ['ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE', 'ONE'],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, too, within `list comprehension`:

```
grid = [[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]

number = 1
if number == 1:
    grid = [["ONE" if y <5 else 0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]

for k in grid:
    print(" ".join(map(str,k)))
```

Output:

```
ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE
ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE
ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE
ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE
ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```